# How do I replace all the special chars which start first in a string

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Input :

```
+---------+
|full_name|
+---------+
|    $raja|
|    #raja|
|    .raja|
```

Expected output :

```
+---------+
|full_name|
+---------+
|    raja|
|    raja|
|    raja|     

val df2 = df1.select("full_name").withColumn("full_name",regexp_replace(col("full_name"), "^[$_]",  ""))
```

My code only removed the `$` from first record. How do I get expected output?

Answer (score 0):

This is because in your regex expression you only search for the `$` symbol at the beginning of the string. Try to add the other symbols you want to replace, like the following:

```
val df2 = df1.withColumn("full_name",regexp_replace(col("full_name"), "^[$#\\._]",  ""))
```

to obtain the expected output:

```
+---------+
|full_name|
+---------+
|     raja|
|     raja|
|     raja|
+---------+
```